# Linking selections in bokeh and slickgrid

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh, slickgrid

I am attempting to create basic web app that allows for linked tables and plots.  The basic set-up is a flask server backend and js front.

The tables are built using slickgrid, the plots are built with bokeh. The basic goal is for selections in the slickgrid plot to be selected in the bokeh plot and vice versa. I know that bokeh's table widget uses slickgrid under the hood, and that bokeh is linking the the selections through a shared ColumnDataSource object.

Are there any examples for how to link bokeh plots and slickgrid tables? The documentation is lacking here.

Comment: As someone who knows Slickgrid but not Bokeh, I can say that this will be largely custom to Bokeh (for example, the ColumDataSource doesn't exist in the vanilla Slickgrid repo). Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. The ColumnDataSource is a bokeh construct, whihc I'm aware they've layered on top of SlickGrid. I just don't see the obvious way that they are feeding data between the two.

Comment: happy to take a look, but I can't find any info about the background of what you're trying to do, eg there are no slickgrid examples I can see on bokeh.pydata.org. example code would be nice :-)